# Using T4 in a VS 2013 project to generate TSQL code

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-generation, t4

My main goal to generate automatically triggers for my (all) table(s) in my SQL database. I am working with VS 2013 so I think it would be efficient to use T4 as templating tool instead of using a 3rd party codegenerator extension, or using a completely standalone SQL server tool to achieve this goal.

I've reviewed many google findings, including T4SQL, but neither seems to accomplish this simple task. I am looking for a simple T4 sample (.tt) what reads metadata from the DB then emits SQL script.

- I do not expect to automatically run these generated scripts, I will run them manually
- I also do not expect these scripts generated automatically, I can generate them on demand.

I am open to alternative suggestions, if one think there is a better and more efficient to generate triggers based on the DB metadata.

Comment: what are you trying to do in your triggers? I've used SQL to generate code with great success before, even excel sheets works well for certain tasks.

Comment: @Jeremy: I would like to do many different things and I should have many different _maintainable_ template. This task asks for a maintainable template solution and not a custom 'SQL writing SQL' what uses string concatenation and other string methods.

Comment: At the end of the day you are just creating a string. why not text files with replaceable fields? I feel like you'll end up writing more code, and more complex code with a code gen framework rather than just creating what you need when you need it.

Comment: @Jeremy: I think conversation became about 'template engine' vs 'custom code writing code'. If you are right, then all template engine are obsolete, Bottom line: I do not want to reinvent the wheel, instead I would like to use a template engine to generate code

Comment: That goes back to my original question of "what do you really want to do?" You're answer was everything, so the short answer is there is nothing out there to do everything for you. You have to know what code you want, then write something to gen the code you want that is custom to your DB situation, whether that be in text files, hard coded SQL or even hard coded sql templates embedded in a vb project. There is no silver bullet.

Comment: I've got a suspicion that this is really a discussion topic, and stackoverflow is intended to be in the format of a specific question with a specific answer. That's not to say that the question here isn't valid - it's something I'm very curious about myself - but maybe it is a bit too big in scope. I'm not sure where the best place would be, but maybe it needs to be taken to a different forum?

Comment: @debater: We are closer with a step to be a discussion with your comment. And also closer with a step with my current comment. Anyway it not turned out what has to do you curiosity with this title.